# Replace tables with divs in pages generated by views

Tags: views, theming

How can I replace the page layout generated by views with the grid format into something  tableless? I need those columns displayed in css stylished divs.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is to edit the View and change the Style Settings from table to unformatted.

Comment: But i want to keep the columns..

Comment: then use css and style the view appropriately: each and every bit of data Views displays is wrapped in all sorts of easily styled divs or spans.

Answer (score 0):

True, especially if you use Views 3, where a lot of options are available via the UI. Almost everything can be done there short of pure CSS stuff.